# Repeated SQL Connections, should I create a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlconnection

I'm still quite new to c# and I have multiple count queries on a single page. I don't need to use these queries anywhere else so have avoided creating a class. Still though, I can help but think there must be a more efficient approach but I was wondering what that would be!

Here's an example

```
    private void cntUp() {
    Dictionary<string, string> crd = getCredentials(Session["secure"].ToString());
    Label UserUpcoming = frmDash.FindControl("lblUserReviewUp") as Label;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString))
    {
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand countUpcoming = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vw_dash_user_upcoming WHERE Employee_ID = @employee_id", con))
            {
                countUpcoming.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("employee_id",     crd["employee_id"].ToString()));
                SqlDataReader readerUpcoming = countUpcoming.ExecuteReader();
                while (readerUpcoming.Read())
                {
                    UserUpcoming.Text = readerUpcoming.GetInt32(0).ToString();
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            Response.Redirect(this.ErrorPage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I personally don't create a class until I know I am going to use something repeatedly.  Like if I see myself writing the same code for a 2nd time.  I will create a class and move all code over to the class

Comment: @DJBurb Thanks for the quick response. Sorry, I should have been more clear. I have wrote the above example five times (with slightly different query and label) but its all on one page, is that normal practice?

Comment: @user2262168 - You should have a single Method that depending on the query does something else.  You should NOT handle the connection through a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only do stuff 1 place, generally you'd make everything less readable. So I would probably avoid it. It's a common pattern, however, to you would do yourself a favor writing a utility class with some functions for this.

```
//requires query parameters to have names @0, @1 etc in string
public static List<object[]> Query(String query, params String[] parameters) //no injection check on this string, be careful.
{
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_CONN_STRING_))
    {
        conn.Open()
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            AddSqlParams(cmd, parameters);
            return Query(cmd);
        }

    }
}

/// <summary>Generic SQL query. Requires open connection.</summary>
/// <param name="cmd">SqlCommand object with all necessary fields configured.</param>
/// <returns>A list of Object arrays (each array is one row).</returns>
private static List<Object[]> Query(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    List<Object[]> results = new List<Object[]>();
    using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            Object[] row = new Object[rdr.VisibleFieldCount];
            rdr.GetValues(row);
            results.Add(row);
        }
        return results;
    }
}

private static void AddSqlParams(SqlCommand cmd, params String[] sqlParams)
{
    for (Int32 i = 0; i < sqlParams.Length; i++)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + i, (Object)sqlParams[i] ?? DBNull.Value);
}
```

Then use like

```
UserUpcoming.Text = Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vw_dash_user_upcoming WHERE Employee_ID = @0", crd["employee_id"].ToString())[0][0];
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to piece that together for me. I think I will benefit from this approach, although I can't see me using it elsewhere there may be more going on the same page in the future.

I'm going to try implementing this method shortly, thanks again!

Comment: no problem, it was more or less copy paste from my files anyway :)

Comment: how we all roll ;) much appreciated though! Easy for a beginner like me to understand and I managed to implement it in minutes! :D

Answer (score 3):

The following Repository works with SQL Server.

Basically, you can either issue a regular or parameterized query.
You can pass in your parameters as all strings, or just as objects if you are going to use models with strongly typed numbers and dates.

You can take out the Release mode info if you don't use such a construct in developement, this is just to make it easier to switch between development and production databases without coding a change.

An example usage would be :

```
      var updateStatement = "UPDATE OCCHistoryHeaders SET ValidatingUsername=@pUsername,ValidatingWorkstation=@pWorkstation,CurrentState = @pCurrentStatus,RejectionReason = @pRejectionReason, AutomatedValidation = '0' WHERE BatchId = @pBatchId";

                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        {"pUsername", Environment.UserName},
                        {"pWorkstation", Environment.MachineName},
                        {"pCurrentStatus", currentStatus},
                        {"pRejectionReason", rejectionReason},
                        {"pBatchId", batchId}
                    };

var absRowsUpdated = _occDb.ExecuteParameterizedNonQueryObjects(updateStatement, parameters);
```

Here is the class...

```
public class SomeRepository 
        {
            private  string _connectionString { get; set; }
            private  SqlConnection _sqlConnection { get; set; }

            public SomeRepository()
            {
                switch (AppSettings.ReleaseMode)
                {
                    case ReleaseMode.DEV:
                        _connectionString = "server=;database=;User Id=;Password=";
                        break;
                    case ReleaseMode.PRODUCTION:
                        _connectionString = "server=;database=;User Id=;Password=";
                        break;
                }            
            }     

            public  DataTable ExecuteQuery(string commandText)
            {
                var dataTable = new DataTable();
                var _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, _sqlConnection);
                var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                try
                {              
                    _sqlConnection.Open();
                    da.Fill(dataTable);                             
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var errorText = string.Format("Occ Repository ExecuteQuery Error : QueryString={0} :: Error={1}", commandText, ex.Message);
                    throw new Exception(errorText, ex);
                }
                finally
                {                
                    da.Dispose();
                    _sqlConnection.Dispose();
                }

                return dataTable;
            }

            public DataTable ExecuteParameterizedQuery(string commandText, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
            {
                var dataTable = new DataTable();
                var _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, _sqlConnection);

                var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                foreach (var entry in parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
                }

                try
                {
                    _sqlConnection.Open();
                    da.Fill(dataTable);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var errorText = string.Format("Occ Repository ExecuteQuery Error : QueryString={0} :: Error={1}", commandText, ex.Message);
                    throw new Exception(errorText, ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    da.Dispose();
                    _sqlConnection.Dispose();
                }

                return dataTable;
            }

            public DataTable ExecuteParameterizedQueryObjects(string commandText, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
            {
                var dataTable = new DataTable();
                var _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, _sqlConnection);

                var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                foreach (var entry in parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
                }

                try
                {
                    _sqlConnection.Open();
                    da.Fill(dataTable);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var errorText = string.Format("Occ Repository ExecuteQuery Error : QueryString={0} :: Error={1}", commandText, ex.Message);
                    throw new Exception(errorText, ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    da.Dispose();
                    _sqlConnection.Dispose();
                }

                return dataTable;
            }

            public int ExecuteNonQuery(string commandText)
            {          
                var _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
                var rowsAffected = 0;

                try
                {              
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, _sqlConnection);
                    _sqlConnection.Open();
                    rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var errorText = string.Format("Occ Repository ExecuteNonQuery Error : Command={0} :: Error={1}", commandText, ex.Message);
                    throw new Exception(errorText, ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    _sqlConnection.Dispose();
                }

                return rowsAffected;
            }

            public int ExecuteParameterizedNonQuery(string commandText, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
            {
                var _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
                var rowsAffected = 0;
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, _sqlConnection);

                foreach (var entry in parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
                }

                try
                {               
                    _sqlConnection.Open();
                    rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var errorText = string.Format("Occ Repository ExecuteNonQuery Error : Command={0} :: Error={1}", commandText, ex.Message);
                    throw new Exception(errorText, ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    _sqlConnection.Dispose();
                }

                return rowsAffected;
            }

            public int ExecuteParameterizedNonQueryObjects(string commandText, Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
            {
                var _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
                var rowsAffected = 0;
                var cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, _sqlConnection);

                foreach (var entry in parameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);
                }

                try
                {
                    _sqlConnection.Open();
                    rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var errorText = string.Format("Occ Repository ExecuteNonQuery Error : Command={0} :: Error={1}", commandText, ex.Message);
                    throw new Exception(errorText, ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    _sqlConnection.Dispose();
                }

                return rowsAffected;
            }

        }
```

Comment: this looks like a more robust approach, thanks for taking time to respond but the method suggested by David fits my needs best I think.

Answer (score 0):

I like to have a separate class for each table in the database. In your case I would have a separate class called vw_dash_user_upcoming, this would have a static method something like...

```
public static int CountEmployees(int employeeId) {
    int returnValue;
    // do database stuff here
    return returnValue;
}
```

I usually create a folder and namespace in my project called "database" and all the database stuff goes in there. Nothing goes in there that's not database access. For me this really helps keep things organized, especially in a large project.

Comment: Thanks @krtrego, if I could up vote you I would. Presumably then, I just assign my DataReader to the return value then simply call it from the page?

Comment: That's a lot of classes.  Why not have one class, such as Employee (in this case) with DB related methods in it?  You should always use a DataHelper class to access the DB.  I'm all for encapsulation but maintenance can be a pain if you have many tables with this example.

Comment: @Steve that's a good point and sounds correct (in my case) since I only need to use each query/table once.

Comment: @user2262168 that's correct, just return the value and assign it to your label wherever it's being called from

Comment: @Steve agreed, depending on the db structure I'll do what you suggested. I mostly suggest a class per table because I think it helps prevent the temptation to put non-database functions and processing in the Employee class.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would create a separate class, simply because it's not a good idea to keep pieces of code with totally different responsibilities in one class. When divided into small classes code is easier to read and maintain.

Communication with database should be separated anyway to make it easier to switch between datasources (e.g. different database servers).